# How to make a request if a field with the uuid type is null?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have an optional field `parent` that has a data type `uuid` . Sometimes this field may be empty.

How to execute a get data request if the field is null?

> invalid syntax for uuid type: "null"

```
const current_file = await this.fileService.findOne({
  relations: ['user', 'parent'],
  where: {
    name: file.originalname,
    user: current_user.user_id,
    parent: request.body.parent,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const current_file = await this.fileService.findOne({
  relations: ['user', 'parent'],
  where: {
    name: file.originalname,
    user: current_user.user_id,
    parent: request.body.parent || undefined,
  },
});
```

This way when `parent` is `null` you actually set the key as `undefined` via the `||` operator.